# Syntax error on server

Tags: python

I've the following line in python:

```
out = {"response": {"status": 200, "message": STATUS_CODES["200"], "data": { article }}}
```

In my machine runs ok(python 2.7) but I get a syntax error on a production server(python 2.6.6).

Do you have any ideas of what this could be?, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: post the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the set syntax `{ item }`, but use `set([item])`.
Your code should read

```
out = {"response": {"status": 200, "message": STATUS_CODES["200"], "data": set([article]) }}
```

Note that the set syntax with curly brackets has only been added in python 2.7. If you want to support lower versions, you're therefore bound to use the older version.

Comment: I just learned about the set syntax recently and was quite surprised I didn't know it before. I then checked the details and found out that it was only added in python 2.7.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why was not working on server in the asker's form with `{item}`?

Comment: @antitrust this new set syntax was introduced in py2.7 only, the server is running py2.6.